# java reflection System.out.println

Tags: java, reflection

I m learning java reflection.
I tried

```
System.exit(3);
Class.forName("java.lang.System").getMethod("exit", Integer.TYPE).invoke(null, 3);
```

and it works. I successfully also ran

```
System.out.println(Class.forName("java.lang.System").getMethod("currentTimeMillis").invoke(null));
```

Now how can i invoke System.out.println reflectively

```
java.lang.Class.forName("java.lang.System").getMethod("out.println", String.class).invoke(null, "Hi!");
```

is giving error.
I know System does not have out function. So suggest a way to call System.out.println reflectively

Here is the complete example

```
public class ReflectionDemo1 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
// java.lang.System.exit(3);
// java.lang.Class.forName("java.lang.System").getMethod("exit", Integer.TYPE).invoke(null, 3);
// java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()
// System.out.println(Class.forName("java.lang.System").getMethod("currentTimeMillis").invoke(null));
// System.out.println("Hi!");
java.lang.Class.forName("java.lang.System").getMethod("out.println", String.class).invoke(null, "Hi!");
}
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`out` is a `static` field of the `java.lang.System` class.

You can use the `Field` class to refer to it

```
Class<?> systemClass = java.lang.Class.forName("java.lang.System");
Field outField = systemClass.getDeclaredField("out");
```

The type of that field is `PrintStream`. You don't need to know that really, but you do need to retrieve the corresponding `Class` object for it.

```
Class<?> printStreamClass = outField.getType();
```

We know it has a `println(String)` method, so we can retrieve that too

```
Method printlnMethod = printStreamClass.getDeclaredMethod("println", String.class);
```

Now, since [`println(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.String%29) is an instance method, we need to invoke it on an instance. Which instance? The one referenced by the `out` field. That `out` field is `static` so we can get it by passing `null` to [`Field#get(object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29).

```
Object object = outField.get(null);
```

Then we invoke the method

```
printlnMethod.invoke(object, "Hi!");
```

Answer (score -1):

I came across this same challenge while working through "Core Java for the Impatient" by Cay S. Horstmann (Excellent read btw).

https://horstmann.com/javaimpatient/

First, obtain a Field object using the reflective `getField` method.

```
Field f = System.class.getField("out")
```

Now obtain a `Method` object from the underlying value of the `Field` object. In this case, it is the static field `out` of the `System` class. You are able to pass in `null` as the argument due to it being a static field.

```
Method m = f.get(null).getClass().getMethod("println", String.class);
```

Finally, invoke the method using the underlying value of the `Field` object.

```
m.invoke(f.get(null), "Hello, World");
```